# How do I set content to be equal to a variable I made?

Tags: html-helper

How do I set content to be equal to a variable I made?

```js
request.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/json');
```

```js
const params = {
  username: "username",
  avatar_url: "",
  content: ,
}
```

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? Based on your code, I assume that by "content" you mean the `Content-type` HTTP header. Yes? Also, you tagged this with [tag:html-helper], which is a feature of ASP.NET. Are you using ASP.NET? I ask, because `setRequestHeaders()` isn't a .NET or C# function, but is available to JavaScript via XMLHttpRequest .

Comment: Please clarify what your problem is and more details about your code. What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 0):

If you are in javascript this would be like :

```
const params = {
  username: "username",
  avatar_url: "",
  content: inputVal,
}
```